# Troubles with floats, difference between period and dot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, firefox

In my Rails app, a user can enter different information.

I am facing a problem with `floats` numbers in Firefox:

When fill in the form on Firefox, if I enter `1.23` in the fields it fails, and the record is not saved considering that the field was blank...
If I enter `1,23` it is recored.

`1.23` and `1,23` works fine in Chrome and Safari

Is there a way to solve this? Any explanations?

here is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@car, @consumption]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :kilometers %>  #float
    <%= f.input :liter_price %> #float
    <%= f.input :total_price %> #float
    <%= f.input :shop %>        #string
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

### EDIT

I added a money gem but it doesn't fix the problem...

Comment: Looks like your FF has European locale set. In fact, it does not matter, what happens in the browser, you should check what comes to Rails. The quick and dirty workaround would be to `String#sub` the input to standardize it.

Comment: How does the form look like? How do you send the data? What data gets sent to your app? Do you process the data client-side or server-side?

Comment: @stefan I added my form

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I need them as float to rework on

Comment: `%w|1,23 1.23|.map { |f| f.to_s.tr(',', '.').to_f } #⇒ [1.23, 1.23]`.

Comment: I wrote a callback before save but it fails.... it still considers the attribute as blank...